# Spring Boot ContextStoppedEvent is not being called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some Quartz job in my application that i need to terminate immediately if my application context get closed. For this purpose i tried to implement ContextStoppedEvent. I am unable to trigger this event after multiple attempt. I need some help in calling this event. 
Below is my code.

```
@Component
public class StopContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStoppedEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StopContextListener.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStoppedEvent arg0) {
            LOG.info("Data base closed successfully");

    }


}
```

**Updated:**

```
@Component
public class StopContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StopContextListener.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent arg0) {
            LOG.info("Data base closed successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: What package is `StopContextListener` and what package is your application's main class in? It may not be getting found by component scanning.

Comment: org.springframework.context.event.StopContextListener and i am using same package in my application.

Answer (score 4):

Given your requirement to "terminate immediately if my application context get closed", I would recommend that you listen for `ContextClosedEvent` rather than `ContextStoppedEvent`. A `ContextStoppedEvent` isn't published as part of the context being closed.

Comment: I have tried it with ContextStoppedEvent as well. Unfortunately no success. Am i missing any annotation that enables ContextStoppedEvent ???

Comment: Have you got your events mixed up? I am suggesting that you listen for `ContextClosedEvent`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per your comment this is how i am doing it. I have updated my post. Please suggest now.